# Dynamically adding controls to a panel - layout question

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net, dynamic, panel

I've successfully been able to add controls (labels, images, buttons, etc) to a panel control (using VB/ASP). This panel control, I refer to it as "insertpanel". Then I add this panel to the main panel on my webpage which I made during design time. The problem I run into is that when I add multiple controls of any type to the panel, they are all added in line with each other. I tried giving my image some css-styling of:

```
.VBCODEimageinsert
{
float:left;
margin:2px;
}
```

That works fine as making the image be at the left side of the panel, and the 5 labels to the right of it. Problem is, the labels are all in line and they don't wrap to the next line. I tried adding a literal of the carriage return/line feed but that didn't seem to work either. What is an easy way of laying out this panel that i'm inserting into another panel? A table? And can I do this if a table will work:

```
mainpanel.Controls.Add(table)
```

Comment: you can add a <br /> instead of the linebreak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add a table, then rows and cells for the other controls. And as mentioned above, you can use a  < br/> instead